# Sort solr response by value in subdocument collection

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I'm using DSE solr to index a cassandra table that contains a collection of UDTs. I want to be able to sort search results based on a value inside those UDTs.

Given a simplistic example table...

```
create type test_score (
  test_name text,
  percentile double,
  score int,
  description text
);

create table students (
  id int,
  name text,
  test_scores set<frozen<test_score>>,
  ...
);
```

... and assuming I'm auto-generating the solr schema via `dsetool`, I want to be able to write a solr query that finds students who have taken a test (by a specific test_name), and sort them by that test's score (or percentile, or whatever).

Comment: I have tried doing this:

    select?q={!tuple}studends.test_scores:"some test"%20_val_:test_scores.percentile&sort=score

and I get this error:

"msg": "child query must only match non-parent docs, but parent docID=2280392 matched childScorer=class org.apache.lucene.search.DisjunctionSumScorer",
"trace": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: child query must only match non-parent docs, but parent docID=2280392 matched childScorer=class 

... but I don't know what to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't sort by UDT fields.

However, I'm not sure what the value of a UDT is here. Perhaps I don't know enough about your use case. Another issue I see is that each partition key is a student id, so you can only store one test result per student. A better approach might be to use test id as a clustering column so you can store all the test results for a student in a single partition. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
id int,
student_name text,
test_name text,
score int,
percentile double,
description text,
PRIMARY KEY (id, student_name, test_name)
);
```

Student name is kind of redundant (it should be the same for every row in each partition), but it doesn't have to be a clustering column.

Then you can sort on any field like so:

SELECT * FROM students WHERE solr_query='{"q":"test_name:Biology", "sort":"percentile desc"}' LIMIT 10;

I've used the JSON syntax described here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchJSON.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically you want to do a **JOIN** between table test_score and students right ?

According to the official doc: http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchQueryJoin.html

Joining Solr core is possible only if the 2 tables share the same partition key, which is not the case in your example ...

Comment: No, there's only one table here, 'students', and the dsetool only creates one solr core.  

EDIT: Unless you're suggesting I change the schema...?

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad, I misread the CQL statement, test_score is a type, not a table.